# How to disable GUI for password promt in Gnome

Tags: ssh

I moved from Xubuntu to Debian and copied id_rsa and id_rsa.pub to ./ssh/

I use a passphrase protected certificate to log in to a remote server. My passphrase contains arrows. Somethin like "Mike" then I press the left arrow twice and then "Smith".

Using Xubuntu, the password prompt was from the terminal, but in Gnome, the password prompt is from a pop-up.

In Debian/Gnome, I tried using the arrows and the keycodes ("Mike^[[D^[[DSmith"), but I cannot unlock the certificate.

When I log in directly to the command line of my computer (using recovery mode) I can log to the remote server server without issues.

When the passphrase contains arrows: How can I unlock the certificate from Gnome?

```
$ ssh -v mike@example.com
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to example.com [1.2.3.4] 
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA (removed)
debug1: Host '[example.com]' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mike/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mike/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password


~/.ssh$ ls -all
total 20
drwx------  2 mike mike 4096 Dec 28 10:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 mike mike 4096 Dec 28 10:18 ..
-rw-------  1 mike mike 1766 Aug  9  2012 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  391 Aug  9  2012 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  444 Dec 28 10:18 known_hosts
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but you could change your passphrase to something that doesn't contain arrows using `ssh-keygen -p keyfile`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to change my passphrase but the issue persisted. I had to disable "Gnome Keyring: ssh key agent" from startup applications.

Answer (score 0):

The issue had nothing to do with arrows in the passphrase. It was the Gnome SSH Key Agent. I disabled it from startup applications an now I can use my certificate again.

Comment: I wonder what is the password to unlock the keyring, since I used my passphras, the login password and the root password, but all of them failed.